# How can I visualize resource demand in an Excel diagramm?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that contains a list of projects.

Columns include project start date, and the efforts for different platforms needed for that project. So for example projects starts 1st of april, and we need 200 hours iOS and 150 hours of web development.

I now would like to have a diagram for each platform that shows for each month how many developers are needed. (the amount of hours that map to "one developer" should be configurable)

For each platform there should be a chart with jan-dez on x-axis and 0-5 (for number of developers) on y. The bar for each month should be calculated based on the start date and platform effort put into the table I mentioned above.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I think you are not asking about how to visualize it, but rather how to calculate it. Once you have a table with sums of hours for each month and dev-type, your diagram creation is simple. Consider rewording your question. ;-)

Comment: makes sense now that I read it again... :-) thx

Comment: Have you tried using pivot tables and diagrams? You should be able to group it by month and sum the hours by type. There is a formula based solution too though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formula based solution for the data, i did not yet divide it by the monthly hours of one developer obviously:

For copy pasting: `=SUMIF($C$2:$C$4,$A7,D$2:D$4)`

[image: SUMIF]

Do you need any more comments or is this sufficiently understandable? You should be able to derive a suitable diagram from that table. Ah and of course i put enough dollars in so you can simply copy down and over from B7 all the way to C18. ;-)

A bit meta: The fact that you have the types in separate columns makes it much easier, because  you only have one criterion for the SUMIF. With multiple ones it becomes interesting. This way you could even slam another column or two next to "web" and it would scale nicely.